# Replace first occurrence of a space with a 'dot'

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I am performing data cleaning operation in one of the tables, sample data:

```
create table cars(make varchar(15), variant varchar(25))
insert into cars values('MARUTI', '1.2 Petrol Vxi')
insert into cars values('MARUTI', '1 2 Petrol Vxi')
insert into cars values('MARUTI', '1.3 Diesel Vdi')
insert into cars values('MARUTI', '1 3 Diesel Zdi')

select * from cars

make    variant
MARUTI  1.2 Petrol Vxi
MARUTI  1 2 Petrol Vxi
MARUTI  1.3 Diesel Vdi
MARUTI  1 3 Diesel Zdi

select variant, REPLACE(variant, '[0-9] [0-9]', '[0-9].[0-9]') as Replaced_val
from cars

variant         Replaced_val
1.2 Petrol Vxi  1.2 Petrol Vxi
1 2 Petrol Vxi  1 2 Petrol Vxi
1.3 Diesel Vdi  1.3 Diesel Vdi
1 3 Diesel Zdi  1 3 Diesel Zdi
```

The above result is not what I am expecting

Expected Output is the space between the two numbers must be replaced by a '.' (dot)

```
variant         Replaced_val
1.2 Petrol Vxi  1.2 Petrol Vxi
1 2 Petrol Vxi  1.2 Petrol Vxi
1.3 Diesel Vdi  1.3 Diesel Vdi
1 3 Diesel Zdi  1.3 Diesel Zdi
```

Can someone please let me know how to go about it.

Comment: Note that string manipulations are notoruosly crappy to do in SQL - even today when SQL server has added a lot of functionality. Is there a reason you do not load them into a program and work there? That would likely be a LOT easier.

Comment: You are probably right, will try in R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @cars table(make varchar(15), variant varchar(25));
insert into @cars values
('MARUTI', '1.2 Petrol Vxi'),
('MARUTI', '1 2 Petrol Vxi'),
('MARUTI', '1.3 Diesel Vdi'),
('MARUTI', '1 3 Diesel Zdi'),
('MARUTI', 'abc XYZ 1 6 Diesel Zdi');

select *, patindex('%[0-9] [0-9]%', variant) as patind, stuff(variant, patindex('%[0-9] [0-9]%', variant)+1, 1, '.')
from @cars
where patindex('%[0-9] [0-9]%', variant) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `SELECT` only from the table then

```
SELECT C.Make,
       C.Variant,
       CASE WHEN T.PtIx > 0 
            THEN STUFF(C.Variant, T.PtIx + 1, 1, '.') 
            ELSE C.Variant 
       END Replaced_val
FROM Cars C CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('[0-9] [0-9] %', C.Variant))) T(PtIx);
```

If you're going to `UPDATE` the table then

```
UPDATE C
SET C.Variant = STUFF(C.Variant, T.PtIx + 1, 1, '.')
FROM Cars C CROSS APPLY (VALUES(PATINDEX('[0-9] [0-9] %', C.Variant))) T(PtIx)
WHERE T.PtIx > 0;
```

> You can change `'[0-9] [0-9] %'` to `'%[0-9] [0-9] %'`

See how it's working on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=441b7ec16c2e06efe47dd9b73db8c0d2)